# What do you call a person who gets mad if you don't agree with them?

Tags: epithet-requests

What do you call a person that gets mad if you don't agree with them?

Comment: ... a big baby.

Comment: Hi Leisa Jackson Newcombe. [tag:single-word-requests] and similar questions require information regarding how the word will be used in a sentence, including an exemplary context in the form of a fill in the blank sentence. This helps us select the best option for you, and one particularly important function is restricting the parts of speech that are applicable. You have one noun, and one adjective, and knowing which one better suits your needs is a little difficult without information such as this.

Answer (score 2):

It may not seem like the obvious answer, because we have come to associate it specifically with racial prejudice, but I recommend **[intolerant](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intolerant)**. The following definition is from *Random House Webster's Unabridged Dictionary*, Second Edition (©1986–2001), as seen on dictionary.com:

> 1. not tolerating or respecting beliefs, opinions, usages, manners, etc., different from one's own …

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a specific noun that describes "a person who is intolerant toward those holding different opinions", then that is precisely the definition for the word ***[bigot](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bigot)*** according to *Oxford Living Dictionaries*.

**Please take note** that the word can often carry connotations of the bigot's intolerance being specifically directed towards a social or racial group.